# visual studio 2013 build openframeworks error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, openframeworks

I have just installed visual studio 2013 and I tried to build openframeworks.
But the build failed, and there is

"Error  1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'ofPtr' to 'bool'  C:\Users\Salamander\Downloads\of_v0.8.2_vs_release\of_v0.8.2_vs_release\libs\openFrameworks\gl\ofVbo.cpp    330 1   openframeworksLib
"

in the error list.

I do not know where the problem is. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers, I just ran into the same issue. Found the answer here:

http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/cannot-open-file-openframeworkslibdebug-lib/17270/3

If you click on the error it will take you to the line in the file where the problem lies. Change that line to this:

```
supportVAOs = ofIsGLProgrammableRenderer( );
```